# How to write the mySQL using left-join for this type of problem?

Tags: mysql, left-join

How do I construct the mySQL query using left-join for this problem?

```
Feed Table
-id
-lastpost_id (The id of the user from USER TABLE who last posted)
-firstpost_id (The id of the user from USER TABLE who first posted)

User Table
-id
-name
```

I wish to get a table like that

```
Result 
-id
-lastpost_id
-lastpost_name
-firstpost_id
-firstpost_name
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select *, a.name as lastpost_name, b.name as firstpost_name from Feed f 
      left join user a on f.lastpost_id=a.id 
      left join user b on f.firstpost_id=b.id
```

The trick is to left join and then alias the table as a or b. That way you can make multiple joins to the same table

Comment: Perhaps it's appropriate to mention that you can call the alias anything you want. A short but _descriptive_ name is recommended for maximum clarity. I'd call them u1 and u2, or maybe u_lp and u_fp.

Comment: A very good point. the only reason i didn't was because it was built into the column name in this case - that is "firstpost_name" and "lastpost_name"